# Canvas doesn't fill up completely

Tags: html, reactjs, canvas

I'm using a canvas in ReactJs and when I want to draw a rectangle that takes up the whole canvas, it doesn't fill up completely, it leaves a little space along the length and width of the canvas.

I emphasize that I am changing the width and heigth of the canvas through css so I use the `canvas.client` property

How can I make it completely full?

My code:

```
const PDFDocumentWrapper = styled.div`
  canvas {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
`;
 <PDFDocumentWrapper>
     <canvas ref={canvasRef}
        onMouseDown={
          e => {
                let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
                 const canvas = canvasRef.current
                 const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
                 handleMouseDown(nativeEvent, ctx);
                }}/>
 </PDFDocumentWrapper>
```

my function:

```
function handleMouseDown(event, ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle="#f00";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.clientWidth,ctx.canvas.clientHeight);

    }
```

Note:
 If I use ctx.width it returns undefined

[image: current view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
function handleMouseDown(event, ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle="#f00";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
}
```

I believe that there may be a difference between clientHeight/clientWidth and height/width due to scaling in your browser.